# How to fetch more than one item from DynamoDB by applying condition on other attributes in Node Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

[image]

I want to read all the Items of this table where postedby attribute value should equals to "Peter"
**partition key in this table is postid.**
I want to access this data using Node Js but not getting exact documentation regarding this question.
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to frequently query by a value it’s best to make that your partition key, either in the base table or in a GSI.

What good is a post ID doing as your PK? Maybe have the PK be the poster and the SK be the timestamp. Now you’ve got your data modeled in the way you’re likely to retrieve it.

Forget what you learned with relational databases. Id suggest spending an hour watching YouTube on DynamoDB schema designs.

Comment: but two partition key can't have same value .

Comment: They can if you have a sort key defined.

Comment: please tell me code to implement in node and assume postedby attribute as sort key

Comment: The developer guide includes Node sample code.